# Python unable to run program

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, pandas

So I've been working on this program for a while and for some reason, Spyder (Anaconda) isn't being able to run the program. I'm guessing it's something stupid like a loop unclosed but I couldn't pinpoint anything and since Spyder won't even give me an error. Just fails to run the program. Here is the full program:

```
    import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Small_businesses1.csv",encoding='latin1')
#create start menu
def menu():
    print("Hello!, Welcome to business analysis, how may we help you?")
    print("A) Help you find a local business based on your criteria?")
    print('B) Provide you with performance analytics of businesses and industries around you?')
    print('C) To access and read an excerpt from our data file:')
    print('D) Provide you an exit from the interface')
menu()
option = str(input("Kindly enter your option here: "))    
      
while option != 0:
    if option == "A":
     print="providing you with local businesses now, please input criteria:"
df=pd.read_csv('small businesses.csv')


w=str(input('enter name here'))
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['Starz Café','V lounge salon','Swapnil Tyres','Game Dome','Pride Super Shopee','Lifeberries healthcare' ,'365 medical','Mad momoz','Monde Collections','Studio Hub IT','Healer Armis','Tumbledry Laundry','VCF healthclub','Max link Sports','Creamstone' ,"Archie's","Milano's café",'Café old skool','Rebellion Apprel','D.C books','Agrwal Sweets','grocers','Ronak super mart','Vision stationary']})
while (w in df):
    print(w)
    if w=='':
     break
if w!=0:
    print("Please enter a valid input from the given list")

x=str(input('enter field here'))
df = pd.DataFrame({"field": ['Food & Hospitality','Beauty, health, fitness','Automotive Repair','Sports & Recreation','General Retail','Medical Services','Medical Services (pharmacy)','Food & Hospitality','General Retail','Technology','Medical services','Cleaning and Maintance','Health, beauty and Fitness','Health, beauty and Fitness','Food & Hospitality','General Retail','Food & Hospitality','Food & Hospitality','General Retail','Stationary & Education','Food & Hospitality','General Retail','General Retail','Stationary & Education']})
while (x in df):
    print(x)
    if x=='':
     break
if x!=0:
    print("Please enter a valid input from the given list")

y=str(input('enter desired operation size here'))
df = pd.DataFrame({"operation size": ['Very small','Moderate-Large' ,'Moderate' ,'Moderate' ,'Small','Moderate' ,'Small','Moderate' ,'Small','Small','Small','Large','Moderate' ,'Moderate' ,'Moderate' ,'Large','Small','Small','Small','Small','Small','Medium','Small','Small']})
while (y in df):
    print(y)
    if y=='':
     break
if y!=0:
    print("Please enter a valid input from the given list")
    
z=str(input('enter preferred mode of service here'))
df = pd.DataFrame({"mode of service": ['Physical dine-in/Online delivery','Physical service','Physical service, Home service','Physcial service','Physical service, Home service','Physical service, Online diagnosis','Physical service','Online delivery','Physical service/remote sevice','Remote/online service','Physical service/diagnosis','Physical service/remote sevice','Physical','Physical','Physical service','Physcial service','Physcial service, Online delivery','Physical service, Online Delivery','Online delivery','Physical service, Home service','Physical service, Home service','Physical service, Home service','Physical service, Home service','Physical service, Home service']})
while (z in df):
    print(z)
    if z=='':
     break
if z!=0:
    print("Please enter a valid input from the given list")
    
if w == '':
    print (x + y + z)
if x == "":
    print(w + y + z)
elif y == "":
    print(w + x + z)
elif z == "":
    print(w + x + y)
elif x == "" and y == "":
   print(w + z)
elif x == "" and z == "":
    print(w + y)
elif y == "" and z == "":
    print(w + x)
elif w == "" and x == "":
    print(y + z)
elif w == "" and z == "":
    print(x + y)
elif w == "" and y == "":
    print(x + z)
    
    
if option == "B":
        #do option B stuff here 
        
        if option == "C" :
          import csv
          f=open('smallbusinesses.csv', 'rt')
          myReader = csv.reader(f)
          for row in myReader:
             print(row)
             
             if option == "D":
                 print("Thank you for using our interface!")
            
        menu()
        option = str(input('kindle enter your option here:'))
            

print="providing you with local businesses now, please input criteria:"
```

And here is an extract from the .csv I've used:[image: small business.csv screenshot goes here]
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to understand how the while loop works! In your case, `while option != 0:` while loop will go into an infinite loop sequence, and the program will fail to run.

Answer (score 2):

I think there might be multiple things wrong with your code, but first I would check the following: it might be stuck in an infinite loop :)

In the beginning your code looks like:

```py
while option != 0:
    if option == "A":
        print = "providing you with local businesses now, please input criteria:"
```

Only if your input is exactly `0`, it will pass this while loop. If it is not, it will enter the while loop and perform an infinite loop there. The print method also doesn't work there because you try to execute:

```py
print = "some text..."
```

This does not work (and actually replaces the builtin `print` method with your string) and you should replace those lines with `print("some text...").

If something is wrong with your `.csv` it could crash there as well but I am not able to check that, and I think you would receive an error if that was the case.

There might be more things wrong with the code (I see more possibilities for infinite loops, for example the `while x in df`), but I would start with these! :)

Comment: Hello! I did realize earlier on that the problem was with an infinite loop but I can't seem to break it, exit() doesn't work, sys.exit() doesn't work, everything else I tried doesn't work. Maybe the problem is with where I write the code? (I'm probably not making much sense here but I'm new to this and a high school student so!) anyways yes any help again would be appreciated! (and as far as the "while x in df" statements go, I did isolate them and run and they did work. So I'm guessing my problem is infinite loops)

Comment: Okey! In that case, what always helps me when debugging code is by using the 'interactive debugger'. You can do this by putting the line `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()' at the point in your code where you want to enter the debugger. Then you can press `n` multiple times and you will see which lines of code are executed in which order. Hopefully you will then see where your code gets stuck. Good luck!

(More info on the debugger: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)

Comment: If `exit()` is not working, it means that you're infinite loop is somewhere earlier in the code I think! It might help putting down some print statements as well to see which lines are reached by your code.

Comment: I didn't know about that debugger so thank you so much! I'll be saving that for later surely! As for now, I've ran the code through the debugger and it's confirmed the suspicions, the issue is in the first while loop after the menu (Line 22/23) but when I try to issue a break() or exit() statement immediately after it, it says that it's outside of the loop! This must sound elementary but I don't know how to put the statement in the loop if that's correct?

Comment: Okay so update: I did try adding a statement before the malfunctioning loop to satisfy the non-zero condition that was causing the infinite loop, the code just runs past it. So what I want to do is: "while option != 0:
    continue
else:
    break"
but pretty obviously that syntax is invalid, and I want to proceed with the options afterwards. Would you know how to execute that?

Comment: another update!: (I'm sorry you're my only help in fixing this!) I managed to replace the original statement with while==0 break  and then added the if statements for if it's not 0. So for option A, and it works! The thing actually runs! Except for the fact that if I select any particular option, it runs every option anyway. So if my option is C it'll run A's input commands too, and if my option is A , it'll print C's read csv statement anyway. Is therea way to disable the other options if one was selected?

Comment: Haha no harm in asking! Great that it runs! As for your other question, I am gonna be honest with you, I would refactor I most of your code. It seems that you have 4 basic functionalities, maybe write methods for each of those functionalities? Then you can call them after you select them with your menu. It would also make sure only the right piece of code is executed. Maybe there is some other code which is general and needs to be executed no matter what the choice of the user, you can put that in another method. This would clean up your code quite a bit!

Comment: Ah absolutely! The only minor issue is that I kinda have absolutely no idea on how to go about executing what you have said to me and thanks to school, I don't really have the time to figure it out anymore, the whole program being due 2 days from now along with 700 other things during exams. (no, they really don't let us off for a second) but I appreciate the help! I think I'm just going to go wing it for now haha